# F ratio independence of numerator and denominator

Tags: distributions, anova, independence

For a particular hypothesis testing problem I have the quantity $F = \frac{\sum_{j=1}^{k} (\overline{X_j})^2}{\sum_{j=1}^{k} \sum_{i=1}^{n} (X_{ji} - \overline{X_j})^2}$ where $X_{ji}$ is the $i^{th}$ sample from the $j^{th}$ standard Gaussian population.

We are given that the random samples $(X_{11}, X_{12}, ..., X_{1n})$ ; $(X_{21}, X_{22}, ..., X_{2n})$; . . . ;$(X_{k1}, X_{k2}, ..., X_{kn})$ are indepedent ***and*** $ ( X_{j1}, X_{j2}, ..., X_{jn} ) $ is independent for $1 \leqslant j \leqslant k$.
My questions are:

1. Why are the numerator and denominator of $F$ 
   independent?
2. Is the whole set {$X_{11}, X_{12}, ..., X_{1n}, X_{21}, X_{22}, ..., X_{2n}, . . . X_{k1}, X_{k2}, ..., X_{kn}$} independent?

I also know that $\overline{X_j}$ and $\sum_{i=1}^{n} (X_{ji} - \overline{X_j})^2$ are independent for $1 \leqslant j \leqslant k$.

Comment: What are you testing?

Comment: The null hypothesis is that the $k$ Gaussian populations all have mean zero (but that isn't what I'm asking).